# How can I best make an impression to a professor advertising for a research role in his lab

Tags: research-process, research-undergraduate

While my job hunt which started a couple of weeks ago has been positive, there are nothing intimately related to my background in mathematics and physics. 
While my grades aren't stellar (2.8/4.0), I've a strong interest in mathematical modelling of physical systems, strong reference and one good grade in a final year scientific research project I did.

Today, I was informed by a recruiter that a position in atmospheric research has opened up in my local university and, with a bit of detective work, I managed to find the hiring professor-great
In his personal webpage, he was open to applicants dropping him an email before making any formal applications.

While I have dropped him a short introduction expressing my interest, how should I make an impact should I be invited to meet him? It means a lot to me to be doing something intimately related to my academic background.

Comment: What type of position is this? Undergraduate, PhD, postdoc? Are you still an undergraduate?

Comment: @astronat This is an associate level position for anyone who have completed his/ her undergraduate degree in the stipulated field as advertised. 
No, I have recently graduated.
From where I come from, there are positions for graduates of a BSc to work alongside researchers while being paid an amount as  if they were industry, all things being equal

Comment: You're going to make a *pitch*.  Think of it as an email equivalent of an "elevator pitch."  Make sure your pitch shows that you have familiarized yourself with what his group does.